# Element could not be found - is this a reference issue?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using React Testing Library and Jest to test my simple React app.

I have a component `MyTabs` that renders a navigation bar to switch tabs when the headings are clicked. So if `tab1Heading` is clicked, it should show tab 1. If `tab2Heading` is clicked, it should show tab 2, and so on. I'm using a simple switch/case to switch between three tabs, and the currently selected tab is stored in `this.state`.

Here's the test I'm writing to test this:

```
 1  it("switches tabs when heading is clicked", () => {
 2    render(<MyTabs />);
 3    const tab1Heading = screen.getByText("Tab 1");
 4    const tab2Heading = screen.getByText("Tab 2");
 5    const tab3Heading = screen.getByText("Tab 3");
 6
 7    fireEvent.click(tab2Heading);
 8    const tab2 = screen.queryByTestId("tab_2_id");
 9    fireEvent.click(tab3Heading);
10    const tab3 = screen.queryByTestId("tab_3_id");
11    fireEvent.click(tab1Heading);
12    const tab1 = screen.queryByTestId("tab_1_id");
13    // click second time to see if elements are present
14    // 1 is already loaded, so click 2, then 3, then again 1
15    fireEvent.click(tab2Heading);
16    screen.debug(); // this shows tab_2_id
17    expect(tab1).not.toBeInTheDocument();
18    expect(tab2).toBeInTheDocument(); // <--- element could not be found in the document
19    expect(tab3).not.toBeInTheDocument();
20    fireEvent.click(tab3Heading);
21    expect(tab1).not.toBeInTheDocument();
22    expect(tab2).not.toBeInTheDocument();
23    expect(tab3).toBeInTheDocument();
24    fireEvent.click(tab1Heading);
25    expect(tab1).toBeInTheDocument();
26    expect(tab2).not.toBeInTheDocument();
27    expect(tab3).not.toBeInTheDocument();
28  });
```

I'm fetching the headings first, then I'm clicking each of them in turn (1 is already loaded, so 2 is clicked, then 3, then 1 again) and getting references of the loaded pages using `queryByTestId` (since they can be null), then clicking the headings again and asserting which tabs should be loaded and which not.

Now the issue is that on line 18, it's failing. I have tried looking at the rendered output using `screen.debug()` (line 16) and it does show the id that I'm trying to assert.

I'm lost here. If `screen.debug()` shows the id, then why is the element not found in the document? Is it a reference issue from destroying and recreating the tabs due to the tab switching? That is, is the `queryByTestId()` returned reference stale now?

I also tried using `waitFor()` in the assertions, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait to capture the element reference until you've triggered the app code that causes the desired elements to exist.

The RTL query methods look at the document *as it is when they are executed* -- they are not "live" pointers that automatically update if the document is changed after they get defined.

Change line 18 to this:

```js
expect(screen.queryByTestId("tab_2_id")).toBeInTheDocument()
```

---

This also explains why your debugging trick is failing: you're changing the environment between the moment when you define `tab2` and when you print the document. This is a case of bad experimental design, and it's something you can see just by looking at the code:

```js
 8    const tab2 = screen.queryByTestId("tab_2_id");

/*
All of the below lines could make the world of line 8 different from
the world of line 16:
*/
 9    fireEvent.click(tab3Heading);
..
11    fireEvent.click(tab1Heading);
..
15    fireEvent.click(tab2Heading);

// all the above lines could change the world

16    screen.debug(); // this shows tab_2_id
```

Comment: It is as you say. All those `expect(tab).not.toBeInTheDocument()`s are just coincidences. Now I have used `screen.queryByTestId()` on all nine `expect`s directly and am having no more problems.